# How to access class in C++/CLI from C#?

Tags: c#, dependencies, c++-cli, dependency-management

I am writing a GUI tool in C# to parse and display the data output of another program written in C.  In order to parse the data I need to know the data structures which are specified in a number of C header files.  Thus I need to incorporate those C header files into my C# project.  My questions are:

1) After some research I came to conclude that the best way is to create a new C++/CLI project in my solution, import the C header files into this new project, write some C++/CLI classes that act as thin wrappers for the data structures defined in the C header files, then reference the C++/CLI wrapper classes from the C# code.  Is this the best approach, or is there a better way?

2) I ran into a reference problem.  Here's my simplified code to illustrate the problem:

Original C header in C++/CLI project

```
#define ABC  0x12345
```

Wrapper class in C++/CLI project

```
#include "my_c_header.h"

namespace C_Wrappers {
    public ref class MyWrapper {
        public:
            property unsigned int C_ABC {
                unsigned int get() { return ABC; }
            }
    }
 }
```

User class in C# project

```
using C_Wrappers;
using System;

namespace DataViewer {
    public partial class MainForm : Form {
        private  MyWrapper myWrapper = new MyWrapper();
        public MainForm() {
            Console.WriteLine(myWrapper.C_ABC.ToString());
        }
    }
 }
```

In the C# project I added a reference to the C++/CLI project (using right click > Add Reference).  During build I got an error in the C# project: "The type or namespace 'C_Wrappers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)."

I thought I did everything I was supposed to.  What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you make sure the C++/CLI project compiled first (as in compiled before the C# project)? If the C# compiles first and the dll wasn't produced for the CLI project, it'll say that.

Comment: Is the C++/CLI namespace inside another namespace?  Use Object Browser to have a look-see.

Comment: have you also put a "project dependency" between those 2 project....

Comment: @HansPassant There's only one namespace in C++/CLI project and it is as shown.

Comment: @alexbuisson - I checked and the C# project is dependent on the C++/CLI project

Comment: @WilliamCustode - The C++/CLI project is built first.  I verified that the C++/CLI project was built successfully and the DLL is present in the Debug folder.

Comment: @ThomasNguyen: if this is a C interface you could use directly **P/Invoke**, map the structures and create a C# wrapper around the **DllImports**. A C++/CLI wrapper is really useful when you have an object-oriented API or want to simulate one.

Comment: http://xmight.blogspot.com/2013/04/cli-bridge-to-connect-c-project-to-csharp.html

Answer (score 24):

In my own solution, I had 4 projects:

1. the **C++ project** and the test code
2. the **C++ DLL project** which only compiles a DLL out of the first project source using dynamic links
3. the **wrapper project** which is only an adapter using C++/CLI, which wraps around the raw C++
4. the **C# WPF project** which was my graphical interface.

Here's my translation of the provided link above.

## The C++ DLL project

Make your C++ code into a DLL lib.

1. Inside Visual Studio, go to **File > New > Project**, Select **Win32 project** from the Visual C++ tab.
2. Choose a name for both the project and the Solution, the solution will have all the projects inside.
3. Inside the assistant for Win32 Application, click **next**, check the **DLL** box, then **Empty project** then click **Finish**.

[image: Project creation]
[image: Project assistant]

### Code to add

This is my C++ header for the dll (minus lot of stuff).

Token.h

```
#pragma once
#define DLLEXP   __declspec( dllexport )

DLLEXP void pop_back(std::string& str);

DLLEXP std::string testReturnString();

DLLEXP int getRandomNumber();
```

There's nothing to change inside the CPP.

Build the project, you should have a DLL and a LIB file to include in the C# project debug dir.

## The C++/CLI wrapper

This project serves as an interface between the native code from the previous project, and managed code of the GUI.

1. Add a new project (class library in Visual C++) (called "Wrapper" in this example) to the solution
2. Add the path to the native project with the additional Include directories
3. Add the native project as a reference for the new project (r**ight click > References... > Add New Link**)
4. In **Properties > Linker > Input**, put the name of the native dll in the delayed loading of DLLs (Computations.dll in this example) field

### The C++/CLI code

My wrapper is only a class which looks something like this (minus my own code).

Wrapper.h

```
#include "Token.h" // include your C++ header

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace Wrapper {

    // noticed the ref?
    public ref class TokenAnalyzer
    {

    public:
        TokenAnalyzer(){
        };

        void Init();
            // use the C++/CLI type, like String^ (handles)
        System::String^ ProcessLine(int lineNbr, System::String^ line);
    };
}
```

Nothing special inside the CPP except that you have to include `#include "stdafx.h"`.

It should also builds into a DLL which you will include inside the C# debug dir.

Just a useful function I found somewhere on SO but don't remember where that you might need. It convert C++/CLI String handle into a C++ standard string.

```
std::string MarshalString (String ^ s) {
        using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
        const char* chars = 
            (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
        std::string os = chars;
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
        return os;
    }
```

## The C# project

Add to the solution a new project (**C # Windows Form** or **WPF** or whatever you want!) and set it as the startup project (**right-click > set as startup project**).

1. Add the C++/CLI project as a reference for the new project
2. Add Directive `using Wrapper;` in source code form

Use it like:

```
/// Store the C++/CLI Wrapper object.</summary>
private Wrapper.TokenAnalyzer mTokenAnalyzer = new TokenAnalyzer();
```

**Update 2016/05/06**

[Ashwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163839/how-to-access-class-in-c-cli-from-c/19164038?noredirect=1#comment61679208_19164038) took the time to make a [sample project](https://github.com/ashwinrs/TweetBank) and a [blog post tutorial](https://ashwin.wordpress.com/2016/05/06/how-to-create-a-c-project-with-c-library/) which may help further.

Comment: For some reason my company is blocking your link :(

Comment: I'm writing a little tutorial inside my answer, won't be long!

Comment: Voilà! This should get you started I hope.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the taking the time to write so much.  But unfortunately it doesn't help me much.  First I don't need to do a native DLL project as I don't have native code other than a bunch of C headers which I can put directly into the C++/CLI project.  Second a reference from C# project to C++/CLI project was created and the dependency is correct (C++/CLI project built before C# project) and the C++/CLI DLL was created successfully, yet the C# code cannot reference any class in C++/CLI (the error says the namespace inside C++/CLI doesn't exist or couldn't be found).  How to fix this?

Comment: Have you put the Dll outputted by the C++/CLI project beside the C# EXE inside the C# project Debug folder? I made myself a post-build event inside the C++/CLI DLL project to copy the outputted DLL automatically into the C# project's debug directory.

Comment: I built the C++/CLI project, then manually copy the DLL from that project to the Debug directory of the C# project, then rebuilt the C# project.  But the error still persists.  Very frustrating!  Any other way to force the C# project to see the C++/CLI DLL?

Comment: Maybe clean and rebuild? When messing around my own project to test yesterday, I got the same problem as you, I cleaned and rebuild and it worked!

Answer (score 6):

For me, the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655936/how-to-use-c-cli-within-c-sharp-application) similar question solved that same error in C#.

(i.e. I had a wrapper header file in my C++\CLI project, but forgot to include a .cpp file as well (even though it only has two lines in it: #include "stdafx.h" and #include "Wrapper.h"))