# Trying to wrap PJSIP library to use it in a C++ project with CLR support

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper, pjsip

I'm trying to use the PJSIP lirbrary in a Visual C++ project with CLR support. After googling for hours and hours and trying I got no clue, why my project will not compile. I will tell you, step by step what I've done so far and I hope you guys can tell me, whats wrong with my configuration.

1. I checked out from the PJSIP repository
2. I opened the solution in Visual Studio 2013 (Express)
3. Visual Studio migrated the projects, after the migration was done, I was able to compile the PJSIP project without further problems, the .LIB file was created, PJSIP does not use CLR
4. Afterwards, I created a new Visual C++ project (with CLR) and tried to access the PJSIP library. Compiling was successful, but linking gave many errors (errors like: call to external reference not possible...)
5. Then, Google meant, it is not possible to call methods of a static library from a CLR supported application. My fault that I thought it would be that easy :-(
6. However, I searched again and then I found the possibility to "wrap" the calls to PJSIP with a CLR wrapper class. This wrapper class is embedded in a DLL. This DLL I can use in my Visual C++ project (here a step-by-step guide, I did #3: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/299da822-5539-4e5b-9ba7-b614e564c9f4/presenting-a-c-library-lib-for-use-in-c-project?forum=vcgeneral)

I can create the wrapper class, it compiles nicely, the DLL is created. I can also reference to this DLL from my Visual C++ project, but if I try to access the methods, Visual Studio compiler says, it does not kwno the methods.

On stackoverflow are many questions regarding this topic, however, no answer solved my problem (i.e. [How to access class in C++/CLI from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163839/how-to-access-class-in-c-cli-from-c))

Here is some code, I hope this makes my point clearer:

```
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjnath.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace PJSIPCLRWrapper {

public ref class pjsipWrapper
{
    static int pjsipInit()
    {
    pj_status_t status;

    /* Must init PJLIB first: */
    // pj_init is a function from the PJSIP lib
    status = pj_init();

    return (int)status;
    }
}
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{   
    // this line procduces error C2882: 'PJSIPCLRWrapper': illegal use of namespace identifier in expression
    PJSIPCLRWrapper.pjsipWrapper.pjsipInit();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I searched the whole day the internet how to fix the problem. I got many solutions however no solution provieded solved my problem. I'm afraid, it is not possible or I make a terrible mistake.

I appreciate your help!
regards
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a static function in C++/CLI, it should be:

```
PJSIPCLRWrapper::pjsipWrapper::pjsipInit();
```

Comment: thank you @matt. i changed the erroneous line to     PJSIPCLRWrapper::pjsipWrapper::pjsipInit(); however, now error C3767 ""PJSIPCLRWrapper::pjsipWrapper::pjsipInit": candidate function(s) not accessible" appears. but the method pjsipInit() exists according to the header file. i tried to remove the "static" keyword, lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any solution for my problem, except, that I switched to Visual C++ without CLR support for my program. Here I can use the complete PJSIP library without a wrapper. Although, I can not use the advantages of CLR :-/

Best regards,
Lukas