# How to pass a string from a c++ program to c program and return

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a string function written in rtstring.c file which simply accept a string and return back the same string.
Then i have included this file in a body.cpp file and i want to pass string from 
this file to c file.
How can I do this please help

**My code**

rtstring.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * rtstr(char * s)
{ 
    return s;
}
```

body.cpp

```
#pragma once 
#include "header.h"
#include "rtstring.c" 
mystring::mystring(string str)
{
    st=str;
}   
string mystring::strreturn(string s1)
{ 
    st=rtstr(s1);
    return st;
}
```

header.h

```
#pragma once
class mystring
{
public:
    mystring(string a);
    string strreturn(string s1);
private:
    string st;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    string rs,s="hi hello";
    mystring str1(s);
    rs=str.strreturn(s);
    cout<<"string from c"<<rs;
    return 0;
}
```

I an getting an error of return type mismatch and many associated error. Please help if there is anyway to deal with it. an example will be helpfull.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code properly and indicate where the error occurs, and the exact error message. In any case: I see std::string being passed to a function taking char*, there's no such conversion (assuming `string` is std::string, hard to tell). Can't you use const char* btw? Also what is mystring supposed to do? Take copies of std::string? You don't need a separate class for that.

Comment: A C++ string is different from a C string which is only a char array

Comment: I'm horribly confused about what you are going to do with this. `std::string` contains all functionality to deal with C-style strings and their copies.

Comment: Use c_str() to get C style string. [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: I,m trying to create a c++ wraper for c which will be a dll to c#

Comment: If you want to interop between C++ and C#, consider a C++/CLI dll in between instead of a C dll. C++/CLI already has builtin functions for conversion between System.String and std::string so you don't need any of this code shown here. And likely less bugs as well.

Comment: stijin can u provide me any link for the following?

Comment: Your included `.c` file is compiled as C++, not C! If you want C, compile it seperately and link to your C project. As-is, it is all C++. And a function is not a "program". From your comments it looks like you try to shoot your foot the most complicated way.

Comment: olaf i have found a way out as per my need i have updated the change as an answer to my own post

Comment: .c file can be included without compiling. At the end everything is c

Comment: Here's a pretty good example wrapping some C++ code to be called from C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163839/how-to-access-class-in-c-cli-from-c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you don't include source files. You should make rtstring.c it's own header, in which you declare the function `rtstr`.

Second, you're using a C++ compiler. If you want it to emulate C, you use `using "C" { ... }`. There are still fundamental differences between proper C and C++, so you're still using a C subset of C++, not actual C.

And finally, if you want to convert an `std::string` to a C string (`char*`), you can use its `c_str()` function.

Comment: `extern "C"` does **not** make the following code C code! It only chenges the ABI and name-mangling to C! The rest still has C++ semantics!

Answer (score 2):

> I an getting an error of return type mismatch

If you were to read the complete error message, I'm sure it would tell you that this is the problem:

```
char * rtstr(char * s)
//           ^^^^^^

string mystring::strreturn(string s1)
//                         ^^^^^^
{ 
    st=rtstr(s1);
//           ^^
```

You are trying to pass a `std::string` into a function that instead expects `char*`.

To solve the problem, don't try to pass a `std::string` to functions that expect a `char*`. You'll probably find `std::string::c_str()` member function useful.

---

> ```
> #include "rtstring.c"
> ```

Don't include source files. Especially don't include source files that were written in another language.

To call a function defined in another source file, just declare the function in the calling source and link the object file of the other source. Remember to set the language linkage when declaring cross-language functions. You'll find header files useful for including function declarations.

Comment: Yes i have done it by returning a pointer. but i need it in a string format

Comment: @nikhil well, you could instead modify `rtstr` to take a `std::string` instead, but then it cannot be implemented in C.

Comment: what if accept as string then convert it in to c type string and pass it to the c specific function

Comment: As I said: You'll probably find `std::string::c_str()` member function useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not much clear to me, but I understand your question.

So, accordingly, one of the simplest way is to write the string into a file using C programming and then reading the same file in your cpp program.

Your C program to write into a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* For exit() function */
int main()
{
   char s[1000];
   FILE *fptr;

   fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");
   if(fptr == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Enter your string:\n");
   gets(s);

   fprintf(fptr,"%s", s);
   fclose(fptr);

   return 0;
}
```

Your cpp program something like this to read the same file.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
void main()
{
              char c,fname[20] = 'program.txt';
              clrscr();
              ifstream in(fname);
              if(!in)
              {
                            cout<<"File Does not Exist";
                            getch();
                            return;
              }
              cout<<"\n\n";
              while(in.eof()==0)
              {
                            in.get(c);
                            cout<<c;
              }
              getch();
}
```

Another option could be to use `pipe()` function. [More details.](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/pipe.html)

Comment: I don't want to use File

Comment: check the next option. Thanks!

Comment: I did find a way without using pipe

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out a way which suits my requirement best.
I appreciate all your help thanks.
Changes i have done is as follows

body.cpp
`

```
string mystring::strreturn(string s1)
{
char *p,arr[9];
char *c=new char[s1.size()+1];
copy(s1.begin(),s1.end(),c);
c[s1.size()]='\0';
p=rtstr(c);
strcpy(arr,p);
st=arr;
return st;
}
```

`
please insert appropriate headers.
"using namespace std;" both in header.h and body.cpp
"#include" in header.h

Comment: its "#include<string>"