# Using c++ dll made from eclipse in visual studio 2012 c#?

Tags: c#, c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, dll

How can I use a c++ dll made from eclipse on visual studio 2012 c#? I already made the dll and tried to reference it in c# but visual studio gives an error that " A Reference to "....dll" could not be added please make sure that it is a valid assembly or com".

I have read about it needs to be a managed com or something? If so, How can I do that in my eclipse c++ dll?

Comment: extern "C" __cdecl(dllexport) blabla_keywords blablaFunction {} to stop name mangling in that C++ code. Then [DllImport("xyz.dll")]extern static blablakeyword blablamyFunc() as a specifier in C#

Answer (score 0):

I made a pretty complete tutorial as an answer of another question here on Stack Overflow.

See [How to access class in C++/CLI from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164038/1218980)

It's not directly answering your question, but it may help you building the dll from Visual Studio which might be easier in that particular case and with this particular goal.

Edit: Other similar questions that might help you or others.

[How to Use C++/CLI Within C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5655936/1218980)

[How do I call C++/CLI from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211867/1218980)