# Implementing webrtc data channel for Windows applications

Tags: c#, tcp, webrtc

does any body know how to implement the WebRTC DataChannel API to Windows applications builded in C# to send TCP messages between clients behind NATs. This is not for a web application, it is Windows based only.

Any inputs or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are no .NET implementations of WebRTC. Currently there are only the JavaScript APIs provided by browsers(FireFox, Chrome, etc.) and the [Native C++/C API](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/checkout), which can be [compiled in windows](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started).

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211867/how-do-i-call-native-c-from-c) may help you import the Native API into .NET but I am not sure if it is possible.

Maybe it is time to start on a .NET wrapper or implementation for WebRTC.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this page: http://opentools.homeip.net/webrtc. It's exactly what your are looking for. WebRTC data stack with c# support and sample app.

Comment: link not wokring