# Stackoverflow on calling native c++ from c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am trying to call native C++ code from C# project. To do that I followed the steps from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211867/how-do-i-call-native-c-from-c).

But I get a stackoverflow exception when I create a huge array in the C++ file. Here is the code:

```
//CSharpTest.h

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CpTest.Class1 instance = new CpTest.Class1();
            Console.WriteLine(instance.DoSomething());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the c++ file

```
// CpTest.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace CpTest {

    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        int DoSomething(){
            int arr[640 * 480];
            return 123;
        }
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

The array declaration is causing the stackoverflow exception.

Earlier when I was running only the native C++ code I increased the stack size by increasing the 'Stack Reserve Size' from the project properties.

But for this case I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have to allocate the array on the stack?

Comment: Not necessarily. But I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Your "native C++" is actually C++/CLI, Microsoft's C++ extensions for .Net interop. I have removed the C++ tag and added c++-cli instead.

Comment: Allocate the array on the heap, or better yet use `std::vector`. Allocating such large arrays on the stack is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  int arr[640 * 480];
```

This array is stored on the stack in a C or C++ program.  The equivalent of `stackalloc` in a C# program.  It requires 640 x 480 x 4 = 1,228,800 bytes of storage.  That is too much, the default size of the stack is one megabyte.  You overflowed the stack, the exception tells you about it.

This is a flaw in the native code, it should never rely on such big allocations to pan out at runtime and should use the free store instead.  Operator `new` in a C++ program, `malloc` in a C program.

And preferrably `array<int>^` in a C++/CLI program, that's a managed array that is stored on the GC heap, just like a C# array.  You'd use pin_ptr<> to allow native code to party on the array.

Technically it is fixable in a C# project, you have to ask for a bigger stack for the startup thread, the one that the operating system creates and calls your Main() method.  You automatically get one when you target x64, the default is 4 megabytes.  But that's not generally an option if you have to interop with existing native code.  You can run Editbin.exe with the /STACK option to patch the EXE file header and ask for a bigger stack.  The post-build event in your C# project can look like this:

```
  set path=%path%;$(DevEnvDir);$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\bin
  editbin.exe /STACK:2097152 "$(TargetPath)"
```

Or run the native code from a thread you create yourself, use one of the [Thread constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that lets you specify the stack size.