# Exposing an ISO C++ class to C#

Tags: c#, c++, mono, c++-cli, pinvoke

I need to expose some C++ classes to C# (I am building on Linux, using mono, so COM is not an option)

The evidence I have gathered so far suggests that the best way to approach this is:

1. Write a wrapper C++.Net class around the ISO C++ class
2. Consume the C++.Net classes from C#

I have the following questions:

- First, is this the "best" way of achieving the goal of exposing ISO C++ classes to C# ?
- So far though, I have not seen any examples that actually show how to do this - can anyone suggest some links, or a code snippet to show how this is done for a dummy class?
- How may I send asynchronous message notifications from the C++ code to the C# code ?. Ideally, I would like to cause the C# class to raise an event, with the received data as an argument

Comment: I agree with Reed Copsey. Basically write a C wrapper around the C++ library and then use C# to interface with the C wrapper using P/Invoke. I find the following reference extremely useful when inter-operating with native libraries : http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do C++/.NET classes on Linux using Mono.  Mono doesn't support Managed C++ or C++/CLI, so there is no way to "Write a wrapper C++.Net class around the ISO C++ class".

Your best option for this is to generate a C API for your C++ class, which can be accessed via [Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx).

That being said, one option for easing this is to use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate the wrappers for you.  It supports generation of C# wrappers from C++ classes (as well as wrappers to other languages), and works well on Linux/Mono.

---

Edit:

For an official "Mono doesn't support mixed mode C++/CLI", see the [Languages page](http://www.mono-project.com/Languages):

> It's important to note that any language that compiles to pure IL should work under Mono. Some languages such as Microsoft's Managed C++ do not always compile to pure IL, so they will not always work as expected, since they are not truly platform independent.

C++/CLI for native interop requires non-pure IL, so it will not work on Mono.

Comment: @Reed: are you sure about not being able to use C++/.Net? Could you send me the link please - I need to show it to someone who insists that it is possible

Comment: @Stick it to THE MAN: Here's a SO answer from a Mono dev: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183377/does-mono-net-support-and-compile-c-cli   I'll see if I can find a more "offical" source, but it isn't supported.

Comment: @Stick it to THE MAN: I edited my answer to show you more details - Mono's language page discusses this, right at the top.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!. You probaly saved me a whole lot of grief going down that path. ok, I'm off to swot over the SWIG and P/Invoke documentation (but not before I have accepted your answer!)

Comment: This is [now possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9247254/332026) on Mono. Mixed-mode C++/CLI is still not supported but they have their own way of integrating with native C++.

Comment: I agree with @Justin that Mono's CXXI is even more suitable for inter-operation between the two worlds, as it does not require a strange C++ alike language extension.

Answer (score 2):

Mono has recently made some pretty big strides with C++ interoperability in [CXXI](https://github.com/mono/cxxi) (pronounced sexy).

[From this posting](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html), the short story is that the new CXXI technology allows C#/.NET developers to:

- Easily consume existing C++ classes from C# or any other .NET
  language
- Instantiate C++ objects from C#
- Invoke C++ methods in C++ classes from C# code
- Invoke C++ inline methods from C# code (provided your library is compiled with -fkeep-inline-functions or that you provide a surrogate
  library)
- Subclass C++ classes from C#
- Override C++ methods with C# methods
- Expose instances of C++ classes or mixed C++/C# classes to both C# code and C++ as if they were native code.

CXXI is the result of two summers of work from Google's Summer of Code towards improving the interoperability of Mono with the C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a C++ managed wrapper around your ISO C++ class like this

```
public ref class MyWrapper
{
    public:
        MyWrapper (void)
        {
            pObj = new CMyUnmanagedClass();
        }
    
        ~MyWrapper (void)
        {
            delete pObj;
        }
    
        int foo(void)
        {
            //pass through to the unmanaged object
            return pObj->foo();
        }
    private:
        CMyUnmanagedClass* pObj;
};
```

I hope this helps,
Regards

Comment: This does not work on Linux/Mono.  There is no support for mixed mode assemblies (or C++/CLI at all) with Mono.