# GCC support for C++/CLI

Tags: gcc, mono, c++-cli

Does somebody know, are there any plans or works to add ECMA standardized C++/CLI language support to GCC (which would emit IL code)?

This question was partially discussed in SOF ([Does Mono .NET support and compile C++ / CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183377/does-mono-net-support-and-compile-c-cli)), but firstly I'm not sure that this imaginary project should be realized as a part of Mono project instead of core GCC one, and secondly I'm interested in novel information on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such work personally (and my opinion of most ECMA standards rhymes with "stubber ramp" after the OOXML debacle), however, the [GCC steering committee](http://gcc.gnu.org/steering.html) are probably the best people to ask [here on their mailing list](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/). That particular mailing list includes in its description:

> All major decisions and changes, like abandoning ports or front ends, should be announced and discussed here.

So I would gather that question about upcoming new front ends would be allowed as well.

Answer (score 0):

There has been work on a CLI front-end and back-end for GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cli.html - but it looks quite dead (latest news from 2009).

Comment: As I understand, that project aims to "classic" C/C++, not C++/CLI, as to following _"The initial focus is on C language (more precisely, C99); C++ is likely to be considered in the future"_