# C# and C++ interoperability in Linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux, interop

I have a C++ project in Ubuntu and i need to call to C# functions. I have found that it can be done with C++/CLI in Windows but haven't found yet anything like this for Linux([GCC support for C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363745/gcc-support-for-c-cli?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I don't have worked before with C#, it's possible to to what i want?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144006/using-c-sharp-dll-in-c-code) answers your question

Comment: @Azeros that is exactly the opposite the user asks. kroketor what you're searching is to embedd Mono on your C project, take a look at this: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/

Comment: @Gusman You are right, thanks. This is what i needed. If you do your comment as an answer i will accept it