# Cross-platform C# implementation of Lua

Tags: c#, .net, mono, lua, luainterface

I'm looking for a way to embed Lua into my cross-platform embed application. The problem is - I haven't found any complete, stable, working implementation of Lua on this platform. I've tried the following (here are the list of repositories and their problems):

- LuaInterface - require me to compile a dll for every platform, unstable, since v2 uses Windows
- KopiLua - errors, even their own samples doesn't work
- AluminiumLua - depends on DLL, therefore, not an implementation
- NLua - based on KopiLua and inherits all the problems
- UniLua - ... it's for unity

Also, most of these implementations fails when I do a simple test:

```
for(i=0;i<100000;i)
    Lua.CallSomeFunctionFromLua()
```

From time to time it invokes an error, especially on KopiLua and LuaInterface.

The question is: is there any complete, stable implementation of Lua strictly in C#, without any platform dependencies?

Comment: NLua is not based on KopiLua.
NLua uses KopiLua only for WindowsPhone (or for pure C# environments). But NLua uses KeraLua (p/Invoking the native Lua).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll not find good pure C# library of lua implementation try to give a chance to [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html) As said in documentation it is portable. You could make C++/CLI interface between **luabind** and your framework like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183377/does-mono-net-support-and-compile-c-cli) It is very risky idea, but you will have depth control on what happening. Since luabind is C++ wrapper of C Lua it will not be too hard to implement interface on C#.