# How to run visual studio 2015 managed c++ test functions in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have managed test Project for VisualStudio 2015 C++ Program,

it working properly but I want to run the same test cases in Linux environment,

for the normal c++ Program I have make files, I don't know how to run the visual studio 2015 managed c++ test project in Linux,
here is my sample program..

```
sample.h


#ifndef GUARD_SAMPLE
#define GUARD_SAMPLE
void method1();
void method2();
void method3();
```

and my c++ program is sample.cpp

```
  #include "sample.h"

  void method1()
{
  int a,b=20,c=30;
  a=b+c;
  cout<<"sum is"<<a;
}

void method2()
{
  int a,b=20,c=30;
  a=b-c;
  cout<<"sub is"<<a;
}

void method3()
{
  int a,b=20,c=30;
  a=b*c;
  cout<<"mul is"<<a;
}
```

And my test program is sample_Test.cpp

```
 #include "sample.h"

  namespace sample_MDM_Test
{
[TestClass]
public ref class sample_Testing
{
public: 
    [TestMethod]
    void Test_method1()
    {
        ::method1();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    void Test_method2()
    {
     ::method2();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    void Test_method3()
    {
     ::method3();
    }
```

i can run c++ application using make file , but how to run these unit test functions in Linux environment(for the windows environment It's fine).

Plese, help me.

Comment: AFAIK neither managed nor native VS C++ unit tests can work on non-windows systems. Personally I would like to use native VS C++ unit tests everywhere as they aren't so macro-infested as other testing frameworks, however I had to stick with boost test.

Comment: @VTT: Is there any way to run managed unit cases in Linux environment ?? Give me any suggestion.

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, there seems to be no way to run them on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sample_Test.cpp is not c++ but c++/cli you cannot run it native in a linux environment. Look here [Does Mono .NET support and compile C++ / CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183377/does-mono-net-support-and-compile-c-cli) for further information.

If you only need native c++ have a look for gtest/gmock as testing framework. That will run on Windows and Linux and there is a Test Adapter that integrates into VS2015.